# Setting selection method in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select, python-addin

I haven't found a way of setting the selection method (Create new, Add to current, Remove from current, Select from current selection) in arcpy. Is it possible to do this and - if yes - how?

I am switching between these methods regularly and having to press a modifier key is somewhat error-prone, so I'd like to create a python add-in toolbar that allows me to select the method directly.

Also, I want to select interactively because the features are more or less picked by gut feeling.

Answer (score 3):

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management and arcpy.SelectLAyerByLocation management both have the optional parameter Selection Type. The value must be one of the following strings:

- "NEW_SELECTION"
- "ADD_TO_SELECTION"
- "REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION"
- "SUBSET_SELECTION"
- "SWITCH_SELECTION"
- "CLEAR_SELECTION"

Comment: I need to select interactively by gut feeling, so select by attribute or by location are not appropriate here. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the Selection menu, then Interactive Selection Method, the choosing your desired selection method?

Comment: Yes of course, and I'd like to shortcut exactly that

Comment: In Customize Mode, in Commands Tab of the customize window, under categories, choose Selection. On the right hand side of the window the associated commands will be listed. Here you will find the Add to Current Selection commands etc. which you can drag and drop onto your toolbars for quick access.

Answer (score 3):

While not answering the specific question, I try to aim at the functionality the OP is seeking. I often use these different selection methods myself, and for convenience I have added a dropdown list to my toolbar (and rearranged some of the other buttons):

[image]

If this is not enough for you, I'd suggest using the built-in system for creating keyboard shortcuts. You can access it from Customize --> Customize mode --> Keyboard... (This is also the place for adding and rearranging buttons.)

There you can create a custom shortcut for, virtually, any function or button in Arcmap.

[image]

Comment: While this does not answer the exact question, it's very close to what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: There are actually all four interactive selection methods available to put them into their own toolbar, and arcmap comes with some quite appropriate icons. So I now have my "click once" interactive selection method change

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do selection by both attribute using [arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) and location using [arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm), but you cannot do selection directly from feature, you should create a temporary layer using [arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm) before doing a selection.

Here is snippet code from the above help:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set the workspace
env.workspace = "c:/data/mexico.gdb"

# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("cities", "lyr") 

# Select all cities which overlap the chihuahua polygon
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "intersect", "chihuahua", 0, "new_selection")

# Within selected features, further select only those cities which have a population > 10,000   
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", ' "population" > 10000 ')

# Write the selected features to a new featureclass
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", "chihuahua_10000plus")
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the selection method is an option on the Select Layer By Attributes tool.

However, I am not sure that a Python AddIn will offer the advantage you seek here.